# Python Modules Replacing Themselves During Load

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I've come across some code recently that uses a trick that makes me rather nervous. The system I'm looking at has a Python extension `Moo.so` file stored outside the path and the developer wants to import it with just `import Moo`. For various reasons neither the file location nor `sys.path` can be changed, and the extension must be loaded with `ExtensionFileLoader` anyway.

So what has been done is to have a `Moo.py` in the path that loads the extension module and then replaces itself in `sys.modules` with the extension module, along the following lines:

```
' Moo.py '

from importlib.machinery import ExtensionFileLoader

loader = ExtensionFileLoader('AnotherNameForMoo', '/path/to/Moo.so')
module = loader.load_module()
sys.modules['Moo'] = module
```

Now this does actually work. (I have some tests of it in rather gory detail in [this repo](https://github.com/0cjs/funny-py-import) if you want to have a look.) It appears that, at least in CPython 3.4 through 3.7, `import Moo` does not bind to `Moo` the module that it loaded and put into `sys.modules['Moo']`, but instead binds *the current value* of `sys.modules['Moo']` after the module's top-level script returns, regardless of whether or not that's what it originally put in there.

I can't find anything in any Python documentation that indicates that this is required behaviour rather than just an accident of implementation.

How safe is this? What are other ways that one might try to achieve a similar "bootstrap" effect?